# Reverse Linked List using Iteration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list

I am getting the desired output i.e the reversed linkedlist on the 3rd iteration in the `console.log` below.

*But I have `return previous` and it still returns the value from the 1st Iteration.*

**Even `console.log(previous)` instead of `return previous`, gives the desired output.**

But now the question is how to display it in the end?

Can someone please explain, what's wrong?

```
  reverse(){
      var current= this.head,previous=null;
      while(current)
      {
        var next = current.next;
        current.next = previous;
        previous = current;
        current = next;
        console.log(previous); //I am getting my answer at the third iteration
      }
      return previous; //
  }
```

```js
class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }

  add(value) {
    var node = new Node(value);
    if (this.head == null) {
      this.head = node;
      this.length++;
    } else {
      var current = this.head;
      while (current.next) {
        current = current.next;
      }
      current.next = node;
      this.length++;
    }
  }

  reverse() {
    var current = this.head,
      previous = null;
    while (current) {
      var next = current.next;
      current.next = previous;
      previous = current;
      current = next;
      console.log(previous);
    }
    return previous;
  }
}

class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

var ll = new LinkedList();

ll.add(3);
ll.add(2);
ll.add(7);

ll.reverse();
console.log(ll.head);
```

Comment: You never set `this.head` to the other side

Comment: The exact question you have is not apperent from the title. Maybe you should change it.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Please [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead of editing the question when you found a solution.

Comment: @Bergi, how do I set `this.head`?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Just assign to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was giving the desired output on `return previous`

All that was needed was to call the function `ll.reverse()` or `console.log(ll.reverse())` for this specific question.

```js
class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }

  add(value) {
    var node = new Node(value);
    if (this.head == null) {
      this.head = node;
      this.length++;
    } else {
      var current = this.head;
      while (current.next) {
        current = current.next;
      }
      current.next = node;
      this.length++;
    }
  }

  reverse() {
    var current = this.head,
      previous = null;
    while (current) {
      var next = current.next;
      current.next = previous;
      previous = current;
      current = next;
    }
    return previous;
  }
}

class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

var ll = new LinkedList();

ll.add(3);
ll.add(2);
ll.add(7);
ll.add(9);
console.log(ll.reverse());
```